# Haskell Binary Tree Function (map)

Tags: algorithm, haskell, binary-tree

How can I define a Haskell function which will apply a function to every value in a binary tree? So I know that it is similar to the `map` function - and that its type would be:

```
mapT :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

But thats about it...

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

You can declare an instance of class `Functor`. This is a standard class for data types which allow a function to be mapped over. Please note how similar the type of `fmap` is to your `mapT`'s type:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Let's assume your tree is defined as

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a
  deriving (Show)
```

Then you can declare an instance of `Functor` this way:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f (Node l r) = Node (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
  fmap f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
```

This is how you can use it:

```
main = do
  let t = Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 3)
  let f = show . (2^)
  putStrLn $ "Old Tree: " ++ (show t)
  putStrLn $ "New Tree: " ++ (show . fmap f $ t)
```

Output:

```
Old Tree: Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 3)
New Tree: Node (Node (Leaf "2") (Leaf "4")) (Leaf "8")
```

You can also define for convenience:

```
mapT = fmap
```

Surely, you can do it without type classes, but it makes the code more readable for the others if you use standard functions (everyone knows the usual behaviour of `fmap`).

Answer (score 6):

I'll pretend this is homework and not give away all of the answer. If I'm mistaken, my apologies.

Probably your `Tree` type looks something like this:

```
data Tree a = TreeNode a (Tree a) (Tree a) | EmptyNode
```

There are two cases here, and you will need to write a `mapT` implementation for each of them:

- An internal node, `TreeNode`, which carries a value of type `a` and has a left and a right child. What needs to be done in this case?
- A terminal node, `EmptyNode`. What needs to be done in this case?

Answer (score 4):

The basic format of the map function applies to both. Let's look at the definition of the map function for lists:

```
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
map _ []     = []
```

We can generalize this like so:

1. You take the first value in the data structure
2. Apply the function to it
3. Recursively call your map function with the remainder of the data structure
4. Pass both the modified value and the recursive call into the constructor for your type.
5. When you reach the end, stop recursing

All you really need is to look at your constructor and the map function should fall into place.

Comment: It's been a long time since I wrote any Haskell... shouldn't that be `map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs` ?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question if the input and output are supposed to be *sorted* binary trees.  If you just naively traverse the tree and apply the function, the output tree may no longer be sorted.  For example, consider if the function is non-linear, like

```
f(x) = x * x - 3 * x + 2
```

If the input has { 1, 2, 3, 4 } then the output will have { 2, 0, 0, 2 }.  Should the output tree contain only 0 and 2?

If so, you may need to iteratively build up the output tree as you strip down and process the input tree.

Comment: You're right that this is an issue in many situations, but I think it's probably overcomplicating things in the OP's situation. Not all binary trees have the property that their elements are all unique or even sorted in a particular order. For example, binary trees can be used to simulate lists with cheap random insertion.